# Fundamental groups of open algebraic varieties

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

Let X be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb C$.
1. Is it possible to compute its fundamental group?
2. If X is two dimensional, what is its fundamental group?
3. Let $X\to \bar X$ be the inclusion to its compactification, and suppose $\bar X-X$ is a normal crossing singularity. What is the relation of the two fundamental groups?

Comment: What do you mean with 'compute'? There are algorithms giving you a triangulation of an algebraic variety, and from that giving a presentation of the fundamental group is trivial, but is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know the exact presentation of the fundamental group.  For example, is it a free group?  Or a finitely presented group and what are the relations?  Is it possible for general varieties? Any reference to understand the algorithm?

Comment: Note that having a presentation does not imply being able to answer your questions—not even, in full generality, whether the presented group is trivial.